# Converting from CEST /CET date string to UTC date string when CEST timezone not installed on the machine

Tags: c#

I need to parse some dates that are in CEST/CET, coming as strings from an external provider, and convert them to UTC.

My current culture on my computer is en-GB and I have the BST timezone installed on my machine, but I do not have CEST. Therefore I cannot use `TimeZoneInfo` to convert between time zones as I cannot instantiate the one for CEST.

How do I do this in C#? I have looked at similar questions here on StackOverflow and googled this but I cannot find a solution that works.

My code currently works with this, but I think it's a hack, still:

```
// dateToParse: "2018-09-04T19:17:37.022363"

var theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse,
    @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss\.ffffff",
    new CultureInfo("sq-AL"),       // this culture info is in CEST. Tried using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as well - nothing changed 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);    // tried putting here DateTimeStyles.None

// Our local time is in BST. 
// CEST and BST are always one hour apart so parsing date during daylight saving times will (probably) still work. 
// I think. Except for that 1h window when the switch happens...
theDate = theDate.AddHours(-1);  // I was hoping to not need this!
var utcDate = theDate.ToUniversalTime(); 

return utcDate;
```

So essentially I am looking for something that understands that the date is in CEST, or CET depending on the time of the year, and not in my current BST time, and knows how to turn that into UTC, factoring in things like daylight saving times.

I don't mind using a library - I have very very briefly looked at NodaTime but didn't find an obvious solution there (there very well might be but I didn't put in the time to reliably look for it).

Any help greatly appreciated.

---

After help from the comments and searching a bit more, this code seems to work well:

```
var theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse,
    @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss\.ffffff",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None);

var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(theDate, timeZoneInfo);

return utcDate;
```

Comment: `DateTime` crucially lacks time zone info. `DateTimeOffset` does not. There's also `TimeZoneInfo` (i.e. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse("2018-09-04T19:17:37.022363"), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time"))`).

Comment: `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")` is exactly the bit I cannot use - this was the path I went on initially. That is because this particular timezone does not exist on my machine (it has UK locales), and I cannot install it on mine nor in the production environment.

Comment: CEST is a fixed offset from UTC. I'm pretty sure your times aren't all CEST, but if they are, the solution is trivial. Otherwise, yes, NodaTime should be able to do what you want, it is not limited to the system-provided time zones.

Comment: I was under the impression that it isn't, and it changes throughout the year due to daylight saving times. So sometimes it's +2:00, other times it is +1:00.

Comment: Actually good comment, @hvd, thank you, I will have to change the question - the dates are CEST or CET, based on the time of the year.

Comment: That's weird, because the time zone database is generally "feature complete" for the world, though admittedly different versions have different zones. `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` returns 137 time zones for me, for example, which includes such lovely things as "Alaskan Standard Time" and "North Korea Standard Time", none of which are remotely close to my location. It also lists "Central *Europe* Standard Time" next to "Central *European* Standard Time", though, so maybe there's the snag.

Comment: I'm in the UK and `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")` returns a timezone.

Comment: Likewise in the UK have 137 timezones on my computer. May be worth running some test code on your production environment to list the timezones it has in case it is just your machine that is for some reason missing these things (if you haven't already).

Comment: I have only 136 time zones installed, according to the `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` call. The question has changed slightly as @hvd noted, I cannot use CEST exclusively, I must switch to CET for the rest of the year not covered by CEST. After eyeballing this a bit more, I _think_ I can use the "W. Europe Standard Time" which also supports daylight savings time, so theoretically it should work. (`var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");`)

Comment: All the "standard" time zones support DST if the zone applies it, the name notwithstanding. E.g. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse("2018-10-28T19:17:37.022363"), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time"))` goes to `18:17:37` while `2018-10-27` goes to `17:17:37`.

Comment: Using `W. Europe Standard Time` should indeed also work, since `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time").HasSameRules(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time"))`. In general you have to be careful with this -- just because zones use DST doesn't mean they apply the same rules for when to DST is active.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, @JeroenMostert, I think that does it. Seems to be doing what I am after.