# c# Convert DateTime from fixed timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, fixed

I'm reading from external API dates like this:

2022-05-13 07:05:00

2022-05-13 13:00:00
...

These dates are fixed in CET time. I want to convert them into UTC format like "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz" so I can see UTC offset +02:00.

The problem is that I didn't find a way how to specify that my date is in CET timezone. Functions like ConvertTime, ConvertTimeToUtc doesn't work.

My code is:

```
    var time = new DateTime(2022,5,26,8,15,00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);    // 2022-05-26 8:15:00 CET
    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    DateTime cet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, tz); // non sense, as no timezone info in time...
    var str = cet.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: why do you need to specify that the date you want to transform in UTC is in CET ?
Can't you just invoke `ToUniversalTime()` and then `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")` ?

Comment: This of any help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292908/converting-from-cest-cet-date-string-to-utc-date-string-when-cest-timezone-not

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where the date/time value you read is ambiguous due to being within a "fall-back"?

Comment: @Jon Skeet That's impossible. If the source timezone is CET then it is not possible to have 2:30am in the spring and on the other hand 2:30am in the fall is ambiguous. It's a very good point of yours but simply there is no solution for that.

Comment: @adamsfamily: I don't see what you're saying is impossible - the *situation* certainly isn't impossible, as you've already said - so the OP needs to know how they want to handle it. It would be impossible to get back to the original instant, but that doesn't mean you can't have a policy of (say) "Always take the earlier of two options" or "Always take the later of two options". Or fail, potentially. Same for skipped times, e.g. 2:30am in the spring - should code encountering that invalid value throw an exception, or coalesce it to a different value?

Comment: @adamsfamily: Basically, dismissing the problem as "impossible" isn't a good idea for any system, IMO. Instead, document the issues and how you want the system to behave in each case.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you look at my proposed answer below, I solved Tomas's problem, I haven't dismissed it. It is possible to convert CET to UTC with taking daylight-saving time in consideration. I was responding to your the edge case in your comment and what I'm telling is that it is physically impossible to have 2022-03-27 02:30:00 CET because there was no such time. CET jumped from 2022-03-27 02:00:00 straight to 2022-03-27 03:00:01. Therefore it's impossible to convert 2022-03-27 02:30:00 CET to UTC because the source date is invalid. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @adamsfamily: Look at the comment history. I specifically talked about fall-back, i.e. in the fall, not the spring. *That's* what you responded to with "That's impossible." I think it's *also* worth considering and testing the genuinely-invalid spring values - but I still don't see what's "impossible" about my first comment. (And your answer doesn't say *anything* about the ambiguous situation. I'm sure it does *something*, but I'd have to consult the documentation for `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` to check what. We have no idea whether that matches the OP's requirements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a cleaner way of doing it:

```cs
public static DateTime ParseCET(string dt)
{
    var cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    var localTime = DateTime.Parse(dt);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, cet);
}
```

The output is consistent and correct, always respecting daylight saving time period:

```cs
// winter time - prints "2/1/2022 11:00:00 AM"
Console.WriteLine(ParseCET("2022-02-01 12:00:00").ToString());

// summer time - prints "8/1/2022 10:00:00 AM"
Console.WriteLine(ParseCET("2022-08-01 12:00:00").ToString());
```

**Edge cases:**

1. When daylight saving time changes from winter to summer time, the clock jumps from **02:00:00** to **03:00:01**, therefore there is nothing like `2022-03-27 02:30:00 CET`.

In this case according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc?view=net-6.0) and exception is thrown:

> If dateTime corresponds to an invalid time, this method throws an ArgumentException.

2. When daylight saving time changes from summer to winter time, the clock jumps from **03:00:00** to **02:00:01**, therefore for instance `2022-10-30 02:30:00 CET` could logically translate to either of **00:30:00** UTC or **01:30:00 UTC**.

In this case according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc?view=net-6.0) standard (winter) time is assumed:

> If dateTime corresponds to an ambiguous time, this method assumes that it is the standard time of the source time zone.

Comment: As noted in comments on the question, it's not immediately clear what this does with ambiguous times around fall-back transitions. Reading the documentation for `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc`, it says: "If `dateTime` corresponds to an ambiguous time, this method assumes that it is the standard time of the source time zone." We don't know whether that's what the OP wants to do, or whether they've even considered it - I would encourage you to mention that in your answer, as it's a frequently-neglected part of date/time work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, thanks, added to my answer.

Comment: I'm also reading DateTime with known time zone from an API but when I try to use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` overloaded by source time zone (UTC) and destination time zone (+3), I get an **offset value** from resulted `DateTimeOffset` as my local PC offset (+1), not an offset from destination time zone. Anyone can explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the hours back using:

```
// Currently CET is ahead of UTC by 2 hours
time = time.AddHours(-2);
```

And then you can format the date time object without worrying about the time zones.

edit: adding daylight saving.

First you have to check whether you are in the time where daylight saving is in effect or not.

To do this first get the datetime, then check if it is in the daylight saving period.
Daylight saving goes into effect at the last sunday of march and is cancelled at the last sunday of october

```
currentTime = DateTime.Now();
string currentMonth = currentTime.ToString("MM");
string currentDay = currentTime.ToString("DD");

// Daylight saving is in effect
if ( currentMonth > '3' && currentMonth < '10' ) {
    time = time.AddHours(-2);
}

// Daylight saving is not in effect
else if ( currentMonth < '3' || currentMonth > '10' ) {
    time = time.AddHours(-1);
}

    // If it is march or october
else if(currentMonth == '3' || currentMonth == '10')
{

    // Find the last sunday
    var lastSunday = new DateTime(currentTime.Year,currentTime.Month,1);
    lastSunday = lastSunday.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    while (lastSunday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        lastSunday = lastSunday.AddDays(-1);
    }
    string sunday = lastSunday.ToString("DD");

     // If it is march, check to see if the day is after or before last sunday
     if(currentMonth == '3'){ 
         if( currentDay > sunday )
         {
             // Daylight saving is in effect
             time = time.AddHours(-2);
         }
         else
         {
             // It is not in effect
             time = time.AddHours(-1);
         }
     }
     // If it is october, check to see if the day is after last sunday or not
     else if(currentMonth == '10'){
         if( currentDay > sunday )
         {
             // Daylight saving is not in effect
             time = time.AddHours(-1);
         }
         else
         {
             // It is in effect
             time = time.AddHours(-2);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: sounds cool! What is the best approach to get correct difference between CET and UTC as daylight saving time issue during winter period?

Comment: That is not what i will consider the proper way to do it, when the calendar changes then you have to change the code as well to `AddHours(-1)` ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I also ended up with this approach. Just manually subtracting hours with `.AddHours()`and then adding back correct offset by `.ToOffset()`. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` does not set correct offset for the destination time zone and I don't know why. See my comment to the accepted answer.